# Add images to product description content programatically in Magento2

Tags: magento2, php, product-images, programmatically, product-description

I want to add images to my product description content block **but I don't want these specific images to appear in the product gallery** ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail').

To add regular images I do it the following way:

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
$product->save();
```

For my description I could do something like that:

```
$descr = "<img src='".$media_path."' />";
$product->setDescription($desc);
```

And get the path of images using:

```
$productimages = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
```

Is there any other type of image I could use to achieve my goal ? Or what way should I use to upload these image and reuse them in my product description ?

Comment: In which file you are adding this code, Controller or Block?

Comment: Standalone script

Comment: See my answer and then check it and let me know if it is working properly.

Comment: This is not the requirement. The question is about adding the images to Magento programmatically, and being able to use them in product descr, but not having them appearing in the product images. The part you describe in your solution I can do already, but how to add images the right way and get their path ?

Comment: You want to add all product images to description?

Comment: No, add new images to Magento, and use them only in the product description, but not as product images. So I need first to upload them programatically then get their url to use it when I set my product description. The issue is that when I use addMediaToMediaGallery it automatically puts them in product images/thumbnails... which I don't want

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you but when you use addImageToMediaGallery the image is automatically added to the product images, which is not the desired outcome. I want to make the images in the product description distinct from the product images (image, small_image or thumbnails)

Comment: The answer of @Mitrarajsinh Jadeja is ok as per your requirement.

Comment: How image1.png is uploaded ?

Comment: You tell him that `I need first to upload them programatically then get their url to use it when I set my product description.` And now see answer code.

Comment: yes, and I still don't see how the image1.png is uploaded programatically

Comment: You mean that you want any uploader to upload image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101003/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-vincent-teyssier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add this to your Standalone script.

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('./descr_images') as $fileInfo) {
    if ($fileInfo->isDot()) {
        continue;
    }
    $imagePath = $fileInfo->getFilename(); // path of the image
    $filesystemIo = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File');
    $filePath = ''; // Path of your local directory image
    $copyFileFullPath = $mediaPath . $imagePath;
    $filesystemIo->cp($filePath, $copyFileFullPath);
    $mediaPath = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    $descImage = "<img src='" . $mediaPath . $imagePath . "'/>";
    $productDesc = $product->getDescription();
    $product->setDescription($productDesc . $descImage);
    $product->save();
}
```

Clear cache and then check it.